# Why do I have to increment value of i in for loop?

Tags: python, regex, loops, for-loop

I have written a for loop for a list where if a value is missing from a list it fills that missing value from another list using regex.
My question is the code I have written below doesn't give me the output that I want
.
But when I increment the value of i I'm getting the output I want.
Why do I have iterate the value of index i to get my desired output if for loop does the same thing?

```
sss=['CP.NO.4-10-AHM-2017','CPNO.181-KB-2017','CPNo.224-5-MB-18','CPNo.224-5-GB-18','CPNo.224-5-KB-18','CPNo.224-5-MB-18']
ben = ['','KB','MB','','','MB']

itern = iter(new_lst2) #to iter the new_lst2

for i,j in enumerate(ben):
    if not ben[i]:
        for k in itern:
            if re.search(r'(AHM|ahm|ALD|ald|AMR|amr|BB|bb|CHD|chd|CHE|che|CTB|ctb|GB|gb|HDB|hdb|JPR|jpr|KOC|koc|ND|nd|PB|pb|KB|kb|MB|mb|HRY|hry|KOB|kob)',k) == None:
                break
            else:
                a = re.search(r'(AHM|ahm|ALD|ald|AMR|amr|BB|bb|CHD|chd|CHE|che|CTB|ctb|GB|gb|HDB|hdb|JPR|jpr|KOC|koc|ND|nd|PB|pb|KB|kb|MB|mb|HRY|hry|KOB|kob)',k)
                ben[i] = a.group()               
                break#i+=1

ben
```

Output I'm getting

```
['AHM', 'KB', 'MB', 'KB', 'MB', 'MB']
```

However after replacing the break statement in else loop and putting i+=1. I'm getting the output I want. Why is that the case in a for loop?

Output I got after replacing break with i+=1 in else loop.

```
['AHM', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'KB', 'MB']
```

Comment: The inner loop iterates multiple times before the outer loop reassigns the next value from the `enumerate` object to `i` and `j`.

Comment: I suspect that you want something like `for s, b in zip(sss, ben): ...`

Comment: I have added break statement and used iter outside the for loop to iterate inner loop. Isnt that correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct as well I could have used zip for both the lists. But why is this not working if I have used break and used iter outside the loop to iterate the inner loop

Comment: Apparently not, but even if you get it working, it's far more complicated than it needs to be. If you want to iterate over two sequences in parallel, that's what `zip` is for.

Comment: Just because `itern` is a dedicated iterator doesn't mean that your outer loop respects changes to `i` that you've made in the body.

Comment: `enumerate(...)` produces `0, ...`, `1, ...`, `2, ...`, etc. No matter what you do to `i` inside the loop, the next value from `enumerate` is what gets assigned to `i`, not the next value greater than the current value of `i`.

Comment: But outer loop iterates regardless. And for inner for loop I have used iter. So aren't both the for loops supposed to run parallely?

Comment: If you are replacing the inner `break` with `i += 1`, I assume it can increment more than once for each iteration of the outer loop. They are in parallel, but `enumerate(...)` and `intern` are *not* advancing at the same speed. (`intern` advances *at least* one step for every step `enumerate(...)` takes.)

Comment: @prathambhatia When you use `i+1` instead of `break`, your code becomes equivalent to `ben = [re.search(pattern, k).group() for k in itern]`. The first string in `ben` is empty, so the inner loop is entered on the first iteration, which overwrites all the elements of `ben` with non-empty strings. After that, the inner loop is never entered again. With `break`, the inner loop only advances `itern` when `ben[i]` is empty, so the two loops will always be out of sync (unless *every* element of `ben` is empty).

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I didn't test why you need increase it because I see you should write it totally different - using `zip()` without inner `for`-loop

```
import re

sss = ['CP.NO.4-10-AHM-2017','CPNO.181-KB-2017','CPNo.224-5-MB-18','CPNo.224-5-GB-18','CPNo.224-5-KB-18','CPNo.224-5-MB-18']
ben = ['','KB','MB','','','MB']

pattern = '(AHM|ahm|ALD|ald|AMR|amr|BB|bb|CHD|chd|CHE|che|CTB|ctb|GB|gb|HDB|hdb|JPR|jpr|KOC|koc|ND|nd|PB|pb|KB|kb|MB|mb|HRY|hry|KOB|kob)'

for index, (text1, text2) in enumerate(zip(sss, ben)):
    if not text2:
        results = re.search(pattern, text1)
        if results:
            ben[index] = results.group()

print(ben)
```

And if you don't know `zip()` then you could use `text1 = sss[index]` instead of inner `for`-loop

```
import re

sss = ['CP.NO.4-10-AHM-2017','CPNO.181-KB-2017','CPNo.224-5-MB-18','CPNo.224-5-GB-18','CPNo.224-5-KB-18','CPNo.224-5-MB-18']
ben = ['','KB','MB','','','MB']

pattern = '(AHM|ahm|ALD|ald|AMR|amr|BB|bb|CHD|chd|CHE|che|CTB|ctb|GB|gb|HDB|hdb|JPR|jpr|KOC|koc|ND|nd|PB|pb|KB|kb|MB|mb|HRY|hry|KOB|kob)'

for index, text2 in enumerate(ben):
    if not text2:
        text1 = sss[index]
        results = re.search(pattern, text1)
        if results:
            ben[index] = results.group()               

print(ben)
```